# Kudan with unity3d object tracking running on windows

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, kudan

kudan community. I'm developing an application where I need to use augmented reality, but my application will run on windows computer with two monitors (where one is projecting the augmented reality), connected with a webcamera. Also I need to track an object (not a marker).

I was testing this with the vuforia library and it works on the unity editor, but doesn't work when I try to compile the application on windows. (I know that now vuforia support universal windows apps, but I can't make this works and also from what I see doesn't support multiple monitors).

So I saw that kudan support windows and object tracking but I read the tutorial and wikis and I can't seem make it work.

Any body can guide me on the right track on how achieve this?

PD. I'm using unity engine 5.4 and windows 10 os

Comment: I could be wrong but from what I know kudan does not do Windows nor object recognition.

Comment: I  also taught that, but on they blog on the entry where they compare vuforia with kudan, they put that it works on windows/osx along side on mobile, and also they mention markerless tracking and slam (3d space with object recognition). So that why I give a change to kudan.
link: https://www.kudan.eu/kudan-news/comparison-kudan-vuforia/

Comment: "Alongside mobile" not sure what they meant there but I don't think it is meant that since Windows then Windows Mobile, since it mentions Linux as well and it has no mobile correspondance.  But to answer your issue, Vuforia 6 does object recognition, UWP and Windows 10 tablets.

Comment: yes I tried with vuforia, and like I said it works on the editor, but when  I switch on build settings to universal app now it disappear for me the ability of use several displays, maybe this another question for another discussion, but that's the main reason of why I'm looking other libraries.